# Are there any Jira plugins for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, jira

We are switching over to SVN+Jira+VS2008 for our .NET development. Are there any plugins for Visual Studio that allow to work with Jira directly from the IDE? It would be great if it could be integrated with SVN support (we use AnkhSVN for now), although it's probably too much to ask. Google did not yield much, only some mailing lists which were mostly about other topics.

Comment: I only found that one [here](http://unimplemented.blogspot.com/2008/05/visual-studio-add-in-suckage-part-deux.html). It is unfinished - but maybe starting point...
And while you're at it, you might want to try [this lib](http://www.xml-rpc.net/) with Jiras Xml-Rpc. Maybe a poor mans Visual Studio Pluign isn't all that difficult to write?!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Atlassian has published a free connector for Visual Studio. It's available from the plugin exchange website : https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/19493

Comment: Nice find! For this I'll accept you. Although it turned out we didn't buy JIRA after all. Oh, well...

Comment: Toggle Atlassian Tool Window is always grey for me. Win7, VS2010, TFS.

Comment: The integration is in a broken state more often than in a working state, and three years after introducing the tool it still is classified as "experimental". There currently is no reliable and supported VS integration connector available from Atlassian.

Comment: Looks like this has been deprecated by Atlassian: https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/06/discontinuing-ide-connectors-support/

Answer (score 4):

The JIRA-VSTD integration already exists; I just found it yesterday.

Check [this](http://almworks.com/tracklink/overview.html) out. It's a commercial product by ALM Works.

I havent personally tried it myself, but in the process of obtaining it.

Answer (score 2):

The [VSJira](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=farmas.VSJira#overview) Visual Studio extension was started in October 2015 and is actively maintained as of this month (January 2018).

Comment: Cool! I've long since moved on, but I'm sure others will find this useful!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has been deprecated by Atlassian
https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/06/discontinuing-ide-connectors-support/

but i download and fix some part of it's connector and now you can download in **visual studio 2015**:
http://u2s.ir/3fknUR

```
fix that i done: extension.vsixmanifest, [Content_Types].xml
```

and zip all file as Atlassian Connector For Visual Studio.vsix

sorry i just test with my jira version and it possible that with new version of jira does not work with this
**tested with JIRA v6.1.4**